# Cross apply on both scalar-valued and table-valued functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, cross-apply

My stored procedure uses cross apply to run several functions within the select. 3 of the functions are scalar-valued, while the last one is table-valued.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetThreadsInArea] 
    @CountryCode nvarchar(10),
    @Latitude float,
    @Longtitude float,
    @DistanceInKm int,
    @Offset int,
    @UserID int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT t.ID, t.[Date], t.[Text], t.Points, func.Distance, func.Messages, t.Color, func.IsOwnThread, func.HasVotedIsUpvote
FROM dbo.Threads as t
    CROSS APPLY
    ( Select
        dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM(t.Latitude, @Latitude, t.Longtitude, @Longtitude) as Distance, -- Scalar-valued
        dbo.GetThreadCommentCount(t.ID) as [Messages], -- Scalar-valued
        dbo.IsOwnThread(t.ID, @UserID) as IsOwnThread, -- Scalar-valued
        dbo.HasVotedIsUpvote(t.ID, @UserID) as HasVotedIsUpvote -- Table-valued
    ) as func
WHERE t.CountryCode = @CountryCode AND func.Distance < @DistanceInKm
ORDER BY t.Date desc
OFFSET @Offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
END
```

This command completes just fine, but when I try running it, I get:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.GetThreadsInArea, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.HasVotedIsUpvote", or the name is ambiguous.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

The 1 row affected also confuses me. The stored procedure shouldn't change any data on any rows. Is it the row that is returned from the table-valued function that has been affected?

**EDIT:**

So this is how the procedure looks now, though I dislike having to use dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM twice, both in the SELECT and in the WHERE. Any solution for this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetThreadsInArea] 
    @CountryCode nvarchar(10),
    @Latitude float,
    @Longtitude float,
    @DistanceInKm int,
    @Offset int,
    @UserID int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT t.ID,
       t.[Date],
       t.[Text],
       t.Points,
       **dbo.Fncalcdistancekm(t.Latitude, @Latitude, t.Longtitude, @Longtitude)** AS Distance,
       dbo.Getthreadcommentcount(t.ID) AS [Messages],
       t.Color,
       dbo.Isownthread(t.ID, @UserID) AS IsOwnThread,
       func.HasVoted,
       func.IsUpvote
FROM   dbo.Threads AS t
       CROSS APPLY dbo.Hasvotedisupvote(t.ID, @UserID) func
WHERE  t.CountryCode = @CountryCode
       AND **dbo.Fncalcdistancekm(t.Latitude, @Latitude, t.Longtitude, @Longtitude)** < @DistanceInKm
ORDER  BY t.Date DESC
OFFSET @Offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
END
```

I tried using its alias Distance, but it just tells me:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetThreadsInArea, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 7]
Invalid column name 'Distance'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you put `scalar` function in `cross apply` just use it in `Select` and use the table valued function alone in `cross apply`. Something like this

```
SELECT t.ID,
       t.[Date],
       t.[Text],
       t.Points,
       dbo.Fncalcdistancekm(t.Latitude, @Latitude, t.Longtitude, @Longtitude) AS Distance,
       dbo.Getthreadcommentcount(t.ID)                                        AS [Messages],
       t.Color,
       dbo.Isownthread(t.ID, @UserID)                                         AS IsOwnThread,
       func.HasVoted,
       func.IsUpvote
FROM   dbo.Threads AS t
       CROSS APPLY dbo.Hasvotedisupvote(t.ID, @UserID) func
WHERE  t.CountryCode = @CountryCode
       AND dbo.Fncalcdistancekm(t.Latitude, @Latitude, t.Longtitude, @Longtitude) < @DistanceInKm
ORDER  BY t.Date DESC
OFFSET @Offset ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Regarding *(1 row(s) affected)* have you enabled execution plan ?

If you don't want to use the function twice then either you can use derived table or use that function alone in `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT t.ID,
       t.[Date],
       t.[Text],
       t.Points,
       cs.Distance,
       dbo.Getthreadcommentcount(t.ID)                                        AS [Messages],
       t.Color,
       dbo.Isownthread(t.ID, @UserID)                                         AS IsOwnThread,
       func.HasVoted,
       func.IsUpvote
FROM   dbo.Threads AS t
       CROSS APPLY dbo.Hasvotedisupvote(t.ID, @UserID) func
       cross apply (select dbo.Fncalcdistancekm(t.Latitude, @Latitude, t.Longtitude, @Longtitude))cs (Distance)
WHERE  t.CountryCode = @CountryCode
       AND cs.Distance < @DistanceInKm
ORDER  BY t.Date DESC
OFFSET @Offset ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. The func HasVotedIsUpvote returns two columns, and I want them both. Should I just type:
func.HasVotedIsUpvote.FirstColumn and func.HasVotedIsUpvote.SecondColumn in the select?

Comment: @TarekOrfali Thats it.. remove function name alone..`func.FirstColumn` and `func.SecondColumn`

Comment: Cool thanks again, I made the changes you told me about, but now I get an error.

Here's the new stored procedure: http://pastebin.com/vy7HD9Gd
And heres the errors I get: http://pastebin.com/UP6pffFs

Comment: @TarekOrfali - I have edited my comment already.. Updated my answer as well.. check it

Comment: I think I know why it complains about the func.Distance.
Since the distance isn't in the cross apply anymore, I need to get it from the select, from the function dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM. I changed it to: AND Distance < @DistanceInKM, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @TarekOrfali - Check now.. function is used just once..though it will not make any difference from first query